# react-native image picker not asking for gallery permission in iOS app

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-image-picker

These are the steps mentioned in the package and I have followed everything:

> Add the appropriate keys to your Info.plist,
>
> If you are allowing user to select image/video from photos, add
> NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription.
>
> If you are allowing user to capture image add NSCameraUsageDescription
> key also.
>
> If you are allowing user to capture video add NSCameraUsageDescription
> add NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key also.

But it doesn't ask for gallery permissions and directly opens up the gallery on the iOS app. Will there be any problem with the app review because of this?

```
react-native : 0.63.3
react-native-image-picker: 4.8.4
```

Comment: Is it possible that you granted it permissions already? *An app can't just open the gallery without asking for permissions.*. Try uninstalling the app and installing it again and read all the permission-asking messages thoroughly.

Comment: Hey @OctavianMărculescu, I did uninstall and install it again multiple times, but it's not asking for permission